# How can Razor can see some Linq methods but not others in the same assembly?

Tags: linq, visual-studio, razor

This one makes no sense.  I've got a Razor view (VB syntax) that has some code that works with the model object.  In one line, it accesses a list and calls `FirstOrDefault`, which lives in `System.Linq.Enumerable`, and this works fine.  But in the very next line, it tries to call `Select` on another list and it gives the error below:

[image: Bizarre Linq Error]

But this is totally bizarre because `FirstOrDefault` and `Select` are in the same namespace in the same assembly.  How could it possibly see one and not the other?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? I use VS2010, and occasionally get errors like that (though not in the same file), and closing all Visual Studio instances will often fix that.

Comment: What happens when you try to call the extension method conventionally, as in `System.Linq.Enumerable.Select()`?  I agree with krillgar; sometimes this is a random VS problem that goes away if you shake the tree a little bit.  What type does `ReturnObjectPropertyShapes` return?

Comment: @krillgar: I've tried it a few times but the problem survives a restart of Visual Studio.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I've tried calling it conventionally with the fully qualified namespace and it doesn't work.  In fact, it shows me Intellisense with all of the available methods on Enumerable, and Select isn't there.

Comment: What type does `ReturnObjectPropertyShapes` return?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The data type is actually a List(Of List(Of SomeObject)), which is slightly complicated, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: I am skeptical.  Try casting it to an `IEnumerable<Whatever>`.  If the cast succeeds (which it might not) you should have access to the Linq extension methods.

Comment: That doesn't help, which on the whole is a relief, because that would mean something else was broken pretty badly.

Comment: The error in your post is a broken line,  can you add the error message and ideally the full call to .Select that is emitting it.

Comment: @tolanj: The line isn't broken, it's just cut off in the screenshot.